# Browser received Set-Cookie Header, but not stored in browser and not sending back to server

Tags: reactjs, node.js, cookies, browser, cors

Any help is much appreciated as I've spent days trying to figure this out. I have a client running on https://localhost.co:3000 using React and a server running on https://localhost.co:3001 using node.js express. Upon sign in and authentication, the server sends a session ID back to the client via cookies:

```
res.cookie('sessionId', sessionId, {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: true,
      sameSite: 'none',
      domain: 'localhost.co',
      path: '/',
      maxAge: 30 * 60 * 1000, // 30 minutes
    });
```

The client did receive the cookie (Set-Cookies header present in network response):

```
Response
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost.co:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 03 Jan 2024 04:44:02 GMT
ETag: W/"27-vo/NvXASMP0DvCspTRAdhM83W48"
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Set-Cookie: sessionId=690dd35d-3d6d-44d6-bd42-40a2c4c66c34; Max-Age=1800; Domain=localhost.co; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 03 Jan 2024 05:14:02 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
Vary: Origin
X-Powered-By: Express
```

but it's not being stored in the browser (nothing in the Cookie Storage) and when I attempt to send it back to the server:

```
const response = await axios.get('https://localhost.co:3001/validate-session', { withCredentials: true });
```

the server receives an empty object:

```
[Object: null prototype] {}
```

I've been doing research trying to eliminate issues such as CORS, I have this in my server:

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: ['https://localhost.co:3000'],
  credentials: true,
}));
```

and making sure I have the correct flag such as the `{ withCredentials: true }` in the axios get request above but still have no luck. The browser is just not storing the cookies it seems, and the request being sent back to the server doesn't even have it in the request:

```
Request
GET /validate-session HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost.co:3001
Origin: https://localhost.co:3000
Referer: https://localhost.co:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.2.1 Safari/605.1.15
```

Sorry for the essay, I'm trying to provide as much detail as possible, and again, any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: please check, may you can get help from here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71501529/receive-express-session-id-from-react-app

Comment: I'm guessing you're not actually using `https://localhost.co`. Does your actual Web origin start with `https://` (as opposed to `http://`)?

Comment: My blog post here can give you some hints on how to see why a cookie is not in a given request https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/ (its not just about ASP.NET Core)

Comment: @HusnainTariq Thank you for the reference, I did check that post and confirmed I have the { withCredentials: true } flag in the GET request, and also have credentials: true on my server but still not having any luck.

Comment: @jub0bs yes both the client and server are using https, not http. But now I suspect if that's actually causing the issue, although that doesn't really make sense as I've read elsewhere that using https should actually eliminate some cookies problems.

Comment: @ToreNestenius Thank you for the post, I've tried to follow your post, but my issue is a bit different from what you described. I did see the Set-Cookie header in the server response, and I don't see it in Application -> Cookies, which aligns with what you described, BUT the difference is I also don't see anything highlighted when I check the "Blocked response cookies" box, which I'm assuming it implies the browser actually accepted the cookie, yet it's not storing the cookie as it should, any idea why this could have happened?

Comment: Often cookies are blocked due to HTTP and not HTTPS or the wrong samesite.  There is also a new thing coming https://www.theverge.com/2023/12/14/24000451/google-chrome-tracking-protection-launch-third-party-cookies-ads

Comment: Also, I would perhaps skip the Domain=localhost.co part in the set cookie.